# Problem with running Uppaal 4.1.22 in Mac OS

Tags: uppaal

I downloaded and installed uppaal 4.1.22 on Mac OS 10.14. I have Java 8 installed.

When opened the  uppaal.jar, a window pops out saying “server exited with error 126. Check OS.” After I close the window, I cannot run simulator or verifier. In fact, when I select simulator or verifier, the same window pops up.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: The background server process is crashing for some reason, perhaps there are some binary/library incompatibilities with the Mac OS version. Could you please run the binary bin-Darwin/server in the terminal and report the errors?

Comment: Same problem on 4.1.23 as well

Comment: @MrDank Could you check this answer? perhaps it's related to security policy:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58854486/2685239